# Create Tag for BHO on SU

Tags: support, tags

Like [google-chrome-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions), please create a tag for [browser-helper-objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Objects) (BHO) on super**user**.

Comment: how many questions use BHO?

Comment: @Sathya, search returns 29 results. The point is BHO related questions should be asked on **superuser** rather **stackoverflow**. However, if you are curious about questions count, then tags like [tag:google-video], [tag:google-sites], [tag:google-tasks] & [tag:google-notebook] have total 2 posts each..

Comment: tags can be 'created' only by adding the tag on the relevant question. That's why I asked how many questions.

Comment: @Sathya, for example [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/146458/my-browserhelperobject-is-detected-by-avg-as-a-malware-what-is-going-wrong) requires BHO tag instead of [tag:Internet-Explorer-8].

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely convinced the need of a tag, but the question has been tagged with [browser-helper-objects](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-helper-objects). I hope you'll find more such questions and tag approriately.

Answer (score 0):

As Sathya stated, make sure that you get enough questions into the tag for the tag to become useful. Tags that have existed for a long time and have only yielded a low amount of questions risk the chance of being pruned over time, whether automatically by some cleanup of the system as well as manually by some monkeys who decide to go on a round of killing off some tags...